# Passing an NSURLRequest/NSURL to another UIViewController results in (null)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsurlrequest

I have two ViewControllers which both are UIWebViewDelegates and in one I have a UIWebview that basically lists a number links.
The first ViewController has this method defined:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        BrowserViewController *browserViewController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:browserViewController animated:YES];
        browserViewController.URL = [inRequest URL];
        [browserViewController release];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But when I actually NSLog the URL property in viewDidLoad in the second controller, I always get (null) for the NSURL.
In addition, if I do an NSLog right after pushing the second controller in the coda above, it actually appears **after** the NSLog in the viewDidLoad method of the second controller.

Anyone has any ideas, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the setURL message to the second controller until after it's already completed and returned to the first one.  You need to do that in the other order:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
 if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    BrowserViewController *browserViewController = [[BrowserViewController alloc] init];
    browserViewController.URL = [inRequest URL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:browserViewController animated:YES];
    [browserViewController release];
    return NO;
  }
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t work like this either. The only way I could access the URL in the second controller, is in viewDidAppear for some reason. viewDiDLoad ad viewWillAppear are not affected and the order doesn’t seem to matter.

Comment: Actually, it seems the order you suggested does make it available in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Can’t really do that, because it’s not the 100% correct answer. I need those variables set in viewDidLoad.

Comment: How is the view for that controller getting created?  Is it loaded from a nib file, or created programmatically?  If from a nib, is it in the main nib, or being loaded from a supplemental nib when the controller inits?  I think it's being loaded from a nib before this code ever runs, so there's no way for that variable to be set in viewDidLoad.  If it HAS to be that delegate method, you'll need to delay loading the view from the nib until the pushViewController call.

Comment: All the views are create programmatically and none are loaded from a NIB.

Comment: When are they being created?  viewWillLoad happens as soon as the view is loaded into memory,  That is, when it's created.